# How to execute a stored procedure directly in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, php-pgsql

I have created a procedure like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_user_ax_register(
   user_name character varying(50), 
   password character varying(300), 
   role_id character varying(10), 
   created_dt date, 
   status boolean, 
   email character varying(50), 
   join_date character varying(30), 
   phone_no bigint, 
   client_address character varying(200), 
   full_name character varying(100), 
   financial_year character varying(10)) 
RETURNS void 
AS $BODY$ 
declare 
begin 
  INSERT INTO ax_register(user_name,password,role_id,created_dt,status,email,join_date,phone_no,client_address,full_name,financial_year) 
  VALUES (user_name,password,role_id,now(),true,email,join_date,phone_no,client_address,full_name,financial_year); 
end 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

and tried to execute it like this:

```
SELECT * from insert_user_ax_register('debasrita','debasrita','client001',now(),'t','abc@gmail.com',now(),'ctc','debasrita','2014-15',9090909090);
```

but it throws the following error :

ERROR: function insert_user_ax_register(unknown, unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown, unknown, unknown, bigint) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 16

Please help me out on this. I am new to pgsql and not able to find out any solution from google. I am using `pgsql 9.1.3`

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Its still not working @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message tells you what you need to be looking for:

> *"No function matches the given name **and argument types**"*

As the function *name* seems correct, it can only be the parameters you are passing. So write down which value is passed for which parameter:

```
'debasrita'                 --> user_name character varying(50)
'debasrita'                 --> password character varying(300)
'client001'                 --> role_id character varying(10)
created_dt date             --> now()
status boolean,             --> 't'
email varchar(50)           --> 'abc@gmail.com'
join_date varchar(30)       --> now()       << first error: now() is not a character constant
phone_no bigint             --> 'ctc'       << second error: 'ctc' is not a bigint
client_address varchar(200) -->  'debasrita'
full_name varchar(100)      --> '2014-15'
financial_year varchar(10)  --> 9090909090  << third error: 9090909090  is not a character literal
```

So you need to either adjust the parameter types, e.g. define `join_date` as date, not as `varchar` or adjust the values that you pass for each parameter.

And finally you need to call the function like this:

```
SELECT insert_user_ax_register(...);
```

rather than `select * from ...`

Comment: Hey thanks!! You rectified my mistake :) But i must say that select * from ... works as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using pgAdmintool just right click on the function or Stored Proc under a schema  and select properties and then paramaeters .Now insert the value which you wannna insert.